# Importing custom created module

Tags: python, function, import, nested-function

So i have created `Custom_module.py` module that i want to import or rather to import specific function in `.py` file that i am currently working on.

for example like this:

```
# Custom_module.py

def test1():
    def test2():
        print("This is test2 function")
    def test3():
        print("This is test3 function")
    
    rest of the test1 func code...
```

The question is next, is it possible to import only test2() nested function in current .py file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can return the inner function as a result of calling the outer function. This way, you can access the inner function when you call the outer function.

This is update version `Custom_module.py`:

```py
# Custom_module.py

def test1():
    def test2():
        print("This is test2 function")    
    def test3():
        print("This is test3 function")
    return test2
```

Now, you can import and use `test2` in another module as follows:

```py
from Custom_module import test1
test2_function = test1()  
test2_function()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function `test2()` in this case  and are not accessible from outside the function where they are defined.

If you want to use `test2()` in another module, you should make it a top-level function by defining it outside of `test1()`.

This is update version `Custom_module.py`:

```py
# Custom_module.py

def test1():
    print("This is test1 function")

def test2():
    print("This is test2 function")

def test3():
    print("This is test3 function")
```

Now you can import and use `test2()` in another python script

Here's an example to illustrate this:

```py
from Custom_module import test2
test2()
```

Comment: that code i provided is simplification of my module. in that test1 func i have created GUI using tkinter, and test2 func is used by that GUI so it cannot be outside test1 func (or i just dont know how to do it). so i would like to use that function in other module without just coping it.

Comment: @G_G Now I understand what you want i've given you another answer